# Practical engineering combinatorial-design optimization problem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations, combinatorial-designs

I am a very experienced electrical engineer. I am kindly asking for help!
There is a practical case in electrical engineering that leads to the following question.

Combinations without repetition (n=10, r=2) or C(10,2)
Using Items: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
List has 45 entries.
https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html

[Combination list C(10,2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngxxl.png)

Basic engineering task is to make 45 separate measurements for each C(10,2)pair.
Alternative is to make automated C(4,2) measurements in groups of four Items C(10,4) to cover again 45 pairs C(10,2).

The questions are:
What is theoretically the minimal number of groups of four C(10,4) to cover all 45 combinations in C(10,2) ?
What combinations C(10,4) are concrete solution ?

My concrete intuitive solution for C(10,4) is:

[Combination list C(10,4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSov9.png)

So I came up with a solution of 10 combinations of C(10,4), which together cover 45 combinations of C(10,2).

Since each of the C(10,4) combinations gives 6 C(10,2) combinations, I have a total of 10x6 or 60 C(10,2) combinations, that is, 60-45=15 double C(10,2) combinations.

Theoretically, to get 45 C(10,2) combinations, 8 C(10,4) combinations should be enough, because 8x6=48 C(10,2) combinations, with only 3 duplicate C(10,2) combinations.

My mathematical knowledge is not enough to prove or disprove that claim.

My further effort was to write a VBA program to randomly calculate the most favorable combinations of C(10,4). After about 400,000 random calculations I got 4 solutions with 10 x C(10,4) given below:

[Random Simulation Solution for Combination list C(10,4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga8od.png)

So, I got solutions that are not better than my intuitive solution, that is, they do not contain less than 10 combinations of C(10,4).

I would appreciate any help in terms of:

1. A concrete solution to the problem in the theoretically smallest possible number of C(10,4) combinations.
2. Theoretical proof for the smallest number of C(10,4) combinations.
3. Tip for a software tool that can help solve the problem.
4. Mathematical classification of the problem and reference to the relevant literature or a solution to a similar problem.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Ten possible solutions]

Comment: This is very long winded. You should summarize your question in the beginning. Is this your question? *What is the minimum number of 4-subsets of 10 items such that each 2-subset of 10 items is included in at least one of those 4-subsets* Please confirm

Comment: @kodlu - Yes, I would say that is exactly my question, summed up in one sentence.

Comment: Great question, so nice to hear from other fields.

Comment: This is similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_golfer_problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/), the best solution requires 9 quads.

> #### Covering Designs
>
> A (v,k,t)-covering design is a collection of k-element subsets, called blocks, of {1,2,…,v}, such that any t-element subset is contained in at least one block. This site contains a collection of good (v,k,t)-coverings.

Here's a solution for a (10, 4, 2) design derived from [their tables](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/show_cover.php?v=10&k=4&t=2)

```
[
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [0, 4, 5, 6],
  [0, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 4, 7],
  [1, 2, 5, 8],
  [1, 2, 6, 9],
  [3, 4, 5, 9],
  [3, 6, 7, 8],
  [4, 5, 7, 8],
]
```

Here's some Python code that verifies that these quads cover all 45 pairs, and lists the number of times each pair is covered.

#### Code

```
# Cover all pairs in a set of 10 items, using quads
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

quads = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [0, 4, 5, 6],
  [0, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 4, 7],
  [1, 2, 5, 8],
  [1, 2, 6, 9],
  [3, 4, 5, 9],
  [3, 6, 7, 8],
  [4, 5, 7, 8],
]

# Count the pairs in each quad
pairs = Counter()
for row in quads:
    for pr in combinations(row, 2):
        pairs[pr] += 1

# List the pairs, from most common to least
print(len(pairs), "pairs")
for pr, cnt in pairs.most_common():
    print(pr, cnt)
```

#### Output

```
45 pairs
(1, 2) 4
(4, 5) 3
(7, 8) 3
(4, 7) 2
(5, 8) 2
(0, 1) 1
(0, 2) 1
(0, 3) 1
(1, 3) 1
(2, 3) 1
(0, 4) 1
(0, 5) 1
(0, 6) 1
(4, 6) 1
(5, 6) 1
(0, 7) 1
(0, 8) 1
(0, 9) 1
(7, 9) 1
(8, 9) 1
(1, 4) 1
(1, 7) 1
(2, 4) 1
(2, 7) 1
(1, 5) 1
(1, 8) 1
(2, 5) 1
(2, 8) 1
(1, 6) 1
(1, 9) 1
(2, 6) 1
(2, 9) 1
(6, 9) 1
(3, 4) 1
(3, 5) 1
(3, 9) 1
(4, 9) 1
(5, 9) 1
(3, 6) 1
(3, 7) 1
(3, 8) 1
(6, 7) 1
(6, 8) 1
(4, 8) 1
(5, 7) 1
```

Here's a [live version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNkM1ugzAQhO9%2DilFyAdWqQtOStBKnXPsGCFUuNY0l46W2aV%2D%5F%5FoEETsz483h297jQr7QQWmMSyjooAwEnPWhAdYDycnQcs1PmGz%2Dz%2DHJssDRG33oiHS6ME1mPnsZPZYRXZBakJ61ln4wVutBswkXGUhIatAxoDxwVxxPHseOLfuZ44ahv%2DsRx5njNOsMBOW114M9bXd%5F445p313WOzDofLrpjbJ97wl%5FlfSlS9Ne0AJatZh2mKNlAFpb%2DIpYGewupQHQnG83tbooAhn5lZuKX8trJdnhoUMXn35XbvM6R1jmSS1seycATtBTOs8kq4wstTZHQkmOXfna51GQ5%2DjBJ6JDsxxjykUOKpUKOWMiS%5FQMVvZor&lang=python) of that code, running on the SageMathCell server.

Comment: Let me thank you! I cannot express enough how delighted I am with your prompt response. You have opened up a whole new world for me that I didn't know existed! Not only did you answer the specific task, but you allowed me to find solutions to similar variations of the problem! Although some improvements have been found in history, if a better solution has not been found in the last 28 years, my conclusion would be that the solution found is the smallest possible set with a very high probability. Surely well enough from an engineering perspective.

Comment: @gooblek My pleasure! It's a vast, fascinating field. And somewhat frustrating. ;) Some problems have elegant optimal solutions when the parameters are right, but when the parameters don't comply you have to mess around with brute-force searches, or try  various modifications of solutions from related problems with nice parameters.

Comment: @gooblek The repository includes proven lower bounds on the solution size for each problem, so you can be sure a solution is optimal if it matches the bound.

Comment: @Karl Thank you for additional explanation! I suspected so from repository explanation but wasn't sure.

Comment: @gooblek There *may* be other 9 quad solutions that are better for your application. Eg, there may be solutions that spread the 9 duplicates over a larger number of pairs.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thank you for your observation! I was aware that there are at least ten equally valid solutions obtained by adding +1 to each element as I attached below the text. In a certain sense, they can all be considered the same solution. But I was not aware that there may be many more possible solutions within the best solution. And we cannot know if and how many there are. This is not covered by the information in the repository. Limiting myself to my specific case, the optimization of the time required for the measurement was achieved. Duplicate measurements will be aggregated or discarded

Comment: @gooblek I forgot to mention earlier that if q is a prime or prime power we can construct perfect  (q^2,q,2) *resolvable* covers, using Galois fields. Here's a demo: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxlkM0OgjAQhO88xcZTQY6eTEg86UMgMUQWs10tsEWNMb67a%2Dtv7KXt5NvpdBpsoW5bcrhamiGdJ6BLoACp3Q5VCYJnVXwnIzYmcFGWh3w9zYGg7QQohxOQA3THA0o9ovGc3gJ5Idw3UJaUDTAFG3D7YKWKo%5FEc2HAPgueY59uBg4Nwaa3uRBlz9YZe45wD81%2DUX%2D7FWhufqpJkQW5UejsmjdayMUMxezby%5FJ5051%5FXr%2DrST9Ze1Mgon%2DlADh77YrJ2k%5FQOS0pmfQ==&lang=sage

Answer (score 0):

$10$ "quads" (sets of size $4$) may be the best you can do.

There are $45$ "pairs" (subsets of size $2$). Each quad will contain $\binom 42 = 6$ of those $45$ pairs. So you need to have at least $8$ quads at a minimum.

You can have a maximum of $5$ quads that do not have any pairs in common between them:
$$0123\quad0456\quad1478\quad2579\quad3689$$
However, each additional quad will necessarily repeat more than one pair already occurring, thus three additional quads will still not include $45$ pairs total. So the minimum number of quads should be at least $9$.

So far my attempts to find $9$ quads that work have been unsuccessful, but I don't have an argument that it is impossible (even my argument that $8$ quads is not reachable is not completely tight).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable insight into your intuitive approach!